# Edit field using AJAX in Laravel

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to update field `$medic->current` according to my logic.
I'm new to ajax and i just need to get it started.

In my code i calculate the difference between two dates { $medic->end_day , current date }. Based on their difference in dates i change the "current" field.
If difference < 0 , current = 0 else current = 1 is what I'm trying to do.

So how to use AJAX to edit the "current" field of `$medic`.
Below is the code.

```
<script>
          window.onload = checkcurrent;
          var today = new Date();   

          @foreach($medics as $medic)
            @if($medic->current == 1)
              function checkcurrent()
              {
                var status = {{$medic->current}};
                var last_date= new Date('{{ \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $medic->end_day)->toDateString() }}');                
                var new_last_date = new Date(last_date.getFullYear(),last_date.getMonth(),last_date.getDate());
                var diff = parseInt((new_last_date - today) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));                 
                if(diff<0)
                {
                  status = 0;

                  $.ajax({ 
                   url: "stocks/{stock_tag}/medications/updatecurrent/{info_id}", 
                  type: "put", 
                  data: { current: 0 } , 
                  success: function (response) { 
                    console.log('success');                    
                  }, 
                  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); 
                  }             
                 }); 
                }                  
                else
                {
                  status = 1;                     
                }                           
              }
            @endif
          @endforeach



      </script>
```

And this is my function in controller too:

```
public function updatecurrent($stock_tag,$info_id)
    {
        $stock = Stock::find($stock_tag);
        $findInformation= Medication::where('id','=',$info_id)->first();

        $id=Input::get('current');
        $stock->under_medication=$id;        
        $findInformation->current=$id;
        $stock->save();
        $findInformation->save();
    }
```

I just want help with the ajax code because rest is fine and working.
When status is 0, I want to edit the "current" field to 0.
How to do this?

Comment: what is an issue?

Comment: Its not working. I'm not even sure if my ajax is defined right

Comment: You can't use blade directives inside `<script>` tags like you're doing.

Comment: Ohhhk... can u suggest me a solution?

Comment: You don't return a json response. Your jquery will wait forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my issue. I actually created a function in the model itself to achieve my result.

Below is the code:

```
public function autocheck()
    {
        $stock =Stock::where('tag_no','=', $this->attributes['tag'])->first();
        $medication =Medication::where('tag','=',$stock->tag_no)->where('current','=',1)->first();        
        $today = Carbon::now();
        list($enddays_day, $enddays_month, $enddays_year) = explode('/', $medication->end_day);
        $last_day = Carbon::createFromDate($enddays_year,$enddays_month,$enddays_day);
        $difference = $last_day->diffInDays($today);

        if ($difference == 0) {
            return "ends today";
        }
        else
        if ($last_day < $today)
        {
            $medication->current = 0;
            $stock->under_medication = 0;
            $medication->save();
            $stock->save();
            return "Finished Medication ";
        }
        else
        {            
            return $difference." day left";
        }        

    }
```

And to make the function work, just use `{{$paramater->function_name()}}`. Below is my code for it:

```
@if ($medic->current == 1)
 <h2>Status : {{ $medic->autocheck() }}</h2> 
@endif
```